# Keras how to save specified variable?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, deep-learning

I want to save my trained model in `keras` with 10 fold cv, and I use the word embedding in my model, so `keras` saved model file is too big, about 550M. and 10 fold trained model is about 5GB.

If I could delete the embedding variable in the saved model,  and just save another variable, I think I could save most file size, because the word embedding array file is about 500M. And then total file size will be reduced to 1GB.

But I can not make it with `keras`.

Also when I try using tf.train.saver in `keras`, something strange happens.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried only to save the weights instead of the whole model as mentioned here: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

```
model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

Comment: what I used is save weights, becuase the embeding part is too big, so just weights is also 500MB, so I want to figure out how to specify variable to save, just removing embedding.